# How to display image during in-memory AngularJS processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm new to JS, so please forgive my ignorance. I have an AngularJS app with a page that holds data in-memory. The page gives the user the ability to filter on the data that is then populated into an ng-grid table. How would you display an image (e.g. a spinner) during the time when the JS is processing the in-memory data? This is what I have tried:

The HTML:

```
<button ng-click="loadingTable()">View</button>
<img ng-show="loading" src="../images/loading.gif" />

<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

The JS:

```
$scope.loadingTable = function() {

    $scope.loading = true;

    loadTable();

    function loadTable() {

    };

    $scope.loading = false;

};
```

Comment: You need to set your loading to false inside the loadTable function after the data has been set.  Javascript is async.

Comment: @BenFelda - Javascript is not async by default. It *IS* single threaded however, so unless you explicitly perform the operation asynchronously then you are going to lock up the UI.

Comment: Even when I set loading to false inside the loadTable function, the image never appears. When I comment out loading = false, the image doesn't display until the data has already been processed and displayed.

Comment: @kimli - That's because you are most likely processing things synchronously, and therefore no $digest loop is going to have a chance to run in order to update the UI. You are going to need to use the $timeout service to queue up your operation asynchronously, and then use the returned promise to set the `loading = false` when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your entire example, but my guess is that you are performing a compute bound operation syncronously inside that function.

The problem is that this will lock up the UI thread, and no $digest loop will run until it is finished. This will have the effect of never actually showing the loading indicator, because it will get set to `true` and then to `false` before `$digest` runs.

**The net effect is the screen will freeze for a bit, and then appear as nothing had happened.**

You can run the operation asyncronously using the `$timeout` service:

```
$scope.loadingTable = function() {

    $scope.loading = true;

    $timeout(function(){
       loadTable();
    }).then(function(){
       $scope.loading = false;   
    });

    function loadTable() {

    };
};
```

Here is a simple demo of this concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/z7838/